# Dielectric equivalents of diamagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, dielectric

Is there a dielectric material that would oppose an electric field such that field lines never enter in the material? An electric analog of diamagnetism

Comment: That's not what paramagnetism is.

Comment: you mean, electric analog to a superconductor? Paramagnets allow magnetic field lines to go through, superconductors don't

Comment: @patta Even then, it's only Type I superconductors that behave in that way. Type II superconductors permit flux tubes.

Comment: so, it should be diamagnetism, not paramagnetism

Comment: I vote to close as it is unclear what is asked.

Comment: Also not sure what is asked, but hopefully a wikipedia page on [Negative-index metamaterial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-index_metamaterial) might be a good place to start.